# Scope based access token with wso2 APIM

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have a GraphQL API published with APIM(version 3.2.0) which is protected by a scope (say a local scope named test_scope which is based on a role named test which has the API subscribe permission). I am using WSO2 IS(version 5.11.0) as an identity provider with oauth/openid connect configured. What I am trying to achieve is below

1. Get the jwt token by login with /oauth2/authorize IS endpoint
2. using the token from step 1 to get jwt token based on my scope (test_scope) with /oauth2/token APIM endpoint.
3. using the token obtained in step 2 to access the api endpoint published with APIM

What I tried so far is using the jwt access token from step 1 to do step 2 using the following curl.

```
curl -i -X POST -u <CLIENT_ID>:<Client_SECRET> -k -d 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=<JWT>' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' https://<IP>:<Port>/oauth2/token
```

When I get the token and invoked the secured API endpoint it says 'User is NOT authorized to access the Resource'. How to get the access token with required scopes to overcome this issue.

Comment: Can you verify whether the token does have the required scope and the application is subscribed to the API?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The application is subscribed to the API. In the step 2 response, the token has the 'default' scope only.

Comment: Seems like the issue is that the token does not having the required scopes. Can you send the token request with the scopes and check? In order to include the scopes in the token, you should request the token with the required scopes.

Comment: 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=<JWT>&scope=test_scope'

Comment: Tried with that as well. Same error. Token still have 'default' scope only